# Glass Mapper: InferType is ignored when querying the SitecoreContext

Tags: c#, sitecore, glass-mapper, sitecore7.1

I have installed the package `Glass.Mapper.Sc.CastleWindsor` in version `3.1.2.11` on my Sitecore 7.1 solution and am trying to work with inferred types. I have the following classes:

```
[SitecoreType]
public class ServiceConfiguration
{
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Service Id")]
    public virtual string ServiceId { get; set; }
}

[SitecoreType(TemplateId = "{26512C19-8D30-4A1E-A2CD-3BA89AF70E71}")]
public class JavascriptServiceConfiguration : ServiceConfiguration
{
    [SitecoreField(FieldName = "Is Header Responsive")]
    public virtual bool IsHeaderResponsive { get; set; }
}
```

And i have this item:

[image]

In my code, I try to get this item from the current context mapped by glass with the following line of code:

```
var serviceConfig = (new SitecoreContext()).GetItem<ServiceConfiguration>("{5436EEC6-1A4D-455F-8EF7-975C51FAE649}", inferType: true);
```

According to the [documentation on inferred types](http://glass.lu/docs/tutorial/sitecore/tutorial17/tutorial17.html), I would expect that `serviceConfig` would be of type `JavascriptServiceConfiguration`, but it is of type `ServiceConfiguration`. Am I missing something? I did not make some specific configuration to glass.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Before types can be inferred they have to be loaded by Glass.Mapper. The more recent version of Glass loads types as and when they are requested but this won't work for inferred types. To resolve this you can force Glass to load the types when the application starts.

First find the GlassMapperScCustom class in your solution. You should then update the GlassLoaders method:

```
    public static IConfigurationLoader[] GlassLoaders()
    {
        var attributes = new AttributeConfigurationLoader("Your assembly name");

        return new IConfigurationLoader[] {attributes };
    }
```

Let me know if this doesn't fix it.

Comment: This fixed it. I changed "SitecoreAttributeConfigurationLoader" to "AttributeConfigurationLoader" in your solution, because the Sitecore one is marked as obsolete ;-)

Comment: @MichaelEdwards Thanks. You should probably get around to updating [Tutorial 1](http://glass.lu/docs/tutorial/sitecore/tutorial01/tutorial01.html) & [20](http://glass.lu/docs/tutorial/sitecore/tutorial20/tutorial20.html) on the Glass site as well.